# how to get the percentage of the grade using c++?

Tags: c++

I'm beginner in C++ so i really need your help here's the problem

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double majorexam,score,long1exam,long2exam,longexam,shortquiz,short1quiz,short2quiz,short3quiz,grade;

    cout<<"Input Major Exam Grade : ";cin>>majorexam;
    cout<<"Input Long 1 Exam Grade : ";cin>>long1exam;
    cout<<"Input Long 2 Exam Grade : ";cin>>long2exam;
    cout<<"Input Short 1 Quiz Grade : ";cin>>short1quiz;
    cout<<"Input Short 2 Quiz Grade : ";cin>>short2quiz;
    cout<<"Input Short 3 Quiz Grade : ";cin>>short3quiz;

    majorexam = score*.04;
    longexam = (long1exam+long2exam)*.03;
    shortquiz = (short1quiz+short2quiz+short3quiz)*.03;

    grade = (majorexam+longexam+shortquiz)*100;

    cout<<"Final Grade : "<<grade;
    return 0;
}
```

write a program that computes the grade of a student using the formula
grade = 40% major exam+30% average of 2 long exam+30% average of 3 short quizzes.

Display the average of two long exams,average of 3 short quizzes the grade of the student. Display also a message whether the student passed or failed. Passing is 75%.

Comment: Your formula looks very off to me.

Comment: Nothing here explains what's wrong with the above code. Is it finished and working perfectly and you're just flaunting it, or does it have compile errors, or does it run but not work exactly as you expect (for all inputs, some inputs)? Please edit your question to include the problem with the code, and also fix the formatting of your code (you can see a preview of the question)

Comment: Do you understand the basic math needed in order to calculate percentages? You need to have that understanding before you can write the code to perform the calculations.

Comment: Probable typo: `cin>>majorexam;`. `majorexam` Is a variable used for output later, based on `score` which is left uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // try this 
  // this should work as you want

   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;

int main() {
    double majorexam,score,long1exam,long2exam,longexam,shortquiz,short1quiz,short2quiz,short3quiz,grade;

    cout<<"Input Major Exam Grade : ";cin>>majorexam;
    cout<<"Input Long 1 Exam Grade : ";cin>>long1exam;
    cout<<"Input Long 2 Exam Grade : ";cin>>long2exam;
    cout<<"Input Short 1 Quiz Grade : ";cin>>short1quiz;
    cout<<"Input Short 2 Quiz Grade : ";cin>>short2quiz;
    cout<<"Input Short 3 Quiz Grade : ";cin>>short3quiz;

    score = majorexam*.04;
    double aveLongExam=(long1exam+long2exam)/2;
    longexam = (aveLongExam)*.03;
    double aveShortExam=(short1quiz+short2quiz+short3quiz)/3;
    shortquiz = (aveShortExam)*.03;
    grade = (score+longexam+shortquiz)*100;
    cout<<"Ave of Quiz:: "<<aveShortExam<<" Ave of Long Exam :: "
    <<aveLongExam<<endl;
    cout<<"Final Grade : "<<grade;
    return 0;
}
```